# Successful pandas install but tests fail (and cannot use)

Tags: python, pandas

Somehow, pandas stopped working properly: crashing python without warning. I was not able to functions such as `pd.DataFrame(data, index)` properly, test suite could not be run.

I ran `pip uninstall pandas` then `pip install pandas` to install the newest release.

Installation process is smooth and returned:

> Successfully installed pandas
>
> Cleaning up...

I can `import pandas` fine, some function works, others (many of them) crash python without warning. I cannot `nosetests pandas`, it crashes python.

Other librairies run their test suites without issue.

I am running python 2.7.5, pandas 0.15.0 under Win 7 32bit.

How can I fix this?